# In R: Getting matching values within a row of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I think my problem is less difficult than it seems to me right now:
In R, I have a data frame with several columns. Two of them are called "PlotId" and "Landuse":

```
     PlotId     Landuse
   ---------------------
    000AEG01   Wiese
    000AEG02   Weide
    000AEG03   Maehweide
    000AEG04   ...
```

"PlotId" contains 50 rows with values from "000AEG01" to "000AEG50", "Landuse" contains three levels: "Wiese", "Weide" and "Maehweide".

For another problem, which I try to solve, I simply need to get the "Landuse"-value for the corresponding "PlotId"-row. SO, I need a command that gives me the information: "Plot 000AEG01 corresponds to Landuse Wiese." And so on for all the other rows, so I probably need to write a loop for that. This information, I would like to get as an object, which I can use then within another loop. I hope, you get what I mean and can help me!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Something like this: `as.character(DF$Landuse[DF$PlotId == x])`? `x` is a value from `PlotId` and `DF` is your dataframe.

Comment: I think you are looking for `?merge`.

Comment: I also agree that merge seems like the way to go here. It appears as if you have a subset of the plotId's that you would like to get the Landuse value for. You could also use the %in% operator.